# Adding sublayer to UITextField without storyboard doesnt style the textfields

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have decided to learn to use Swift without storyboards. Before making the switch, I had a function in a file called `Utilities.swift` that has a function to style the text fields, which worked fine when I had a storyboard.

```
class Utilities {

static func styleTextField(_ textfield:UITextField) {


    let bottomLine = CALayer()

    bottomLine.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: textfield.frame.height - 2, width: textfield.frame.width, height: 2)
    bottomLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 48/255, green: 173/255, blue: 99/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
    textfield.borderStyle = .none
    textfield.layer.addSublayer(bottomLine)

}
}
```

Then in my view controller, I have `let firstName = UITextField()` and then a function for `Utilities.styleTextField(firstName)`, which when I had storyboards, worked fine. After removing storyboards and adding constraints programmatically, I can see the text field but it is default without styling.

Comment: You need to share the code that uses this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that, at this point, you didn't set the text field's frame yet, so the `CALayer` is not being drawn because its size is `(width: 0, height: 0)`.

When you get the component from IB, it comes with a frame, which is the one you set in the tool.

Try setting the frame before calling the function.

Comment: right, it makes sense. I have constraints for the text field so is it possible to make the text field's frame the constraints of the text field?

Comment: ok I figured it out. I just did firstName.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width - 80 , height: 30 ) and it works now. Thanks.